# LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

So I'm using Visual Basic C++ 2010 to right my Visual Hello World project for school. I've gotten the code written but I keep getting 'LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined'.

I've looked under

> **Properties -> Linker -> System** >

for the Configuration and it's blank. This is my code. Can you point it out on where I need to define my entry point?

```
    #pragma once

namespace Visual_Hello_World {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for HelloWorld
/// </summary>
public ref class HelloWorld : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    HelloWorld(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~HelloWorld()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
protected: 
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label2;

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Modern No. 20", 20.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
            static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(56, 105);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(166, 44);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->button1->Text = L"&Click Me!";
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &HelloWorld::button1_Click);
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this->label1->AutoSize = true;
        this->label1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Modern No. 20", 26.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
            static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
        this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(38, 31);
        this->label1->Name = L"label1";
        this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(204, 36);
        this->label1->TabIndex = 1;
        this->label1->Text = L"Hello World!";
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this->label2->AutoSize = true;
        this->label2->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Modern No. 20", 21.75F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point, 
            static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
        this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(50, 181);
        this->label2->Name = L"label2";
        this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(184, 31);
        this->label2->TabIndex = 2;
        this->label2->Text = L"For a surprise!";
        // 
        // HelloWorld
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 262);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Name = L"HelloWorld";
        this->Text = L"HelloWorld";
        this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &HelloWorld::HelloWorld_Load);
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void HelloWorld_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         }
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             MessageBox::Show ("Fun Fact: the Pharaoh Tutankhamun died when he was 19 years old after a severe infection set in his leg, which was wounded in battle. King Tut's leg was crushed, resulting in him having to walk around with a cane. King Tut has the largest collection of canes to date.");
         }
};
```

}

Comment: The linker is asking where the entry program point (usually some form of static function such as main() ) is defined. Do you where ?

Comment: no i do not know where it would go

Comment: You don't know where to go because you don't know what language you are using.  This is **not** Visual Basic and is not C++, the language is called C++/CLI.  It resembles C++, but only in passing.  A programmer having no idea what language he's using is rather a severe problem, you need a lot of help that's not readily available on a Q+A site like this.  You really *do* have to read a book about the language to know how to program it correctly.  Such a book will also explain how to write required Main() entrypoint.

Comment: @HansPassant: My programming teacher said it was C++ Programming, and I downloaded it off of Microsoft.com under 'Visual Basic'. I have only been taking Programming for about a year now, so please understand that I am a novice at this. I do not have a book for this class; I go online. I appreciate that you took the time to comment, but, again, I AM A NOVICE. I don't know what I'm doing; hence why I asked for help. Thank you.

Comment: Talk to your teacher, it is his *job* to help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong; I was using a **CLR Console Application** instead of a **Windows Form Application**.

For future reference for anyone else who takes C++ Programming using *Microsoft Visual 2010 Express*; make sure that you are using the correct format. Otherwise, the program **will not work**.

Thanks to everyone who wrote helpful answers!

Answer (score 0):

```
//for CLR windows form on MyForm.cpp use:
#include "MyForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThreadAttribute]
    void Main(array<String^>^ args) {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    //WinformCDemo is your project name
    WinformCDemo::MyForm1 form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}

// under Configuration Properties/Linker/Advanced/entry point set it to Main.
// under Configuration Properites/Linker/System/SubSystem   set it to Windows 
(/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)
```